# mdf & ldf (MS SQL) - импорт в PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, postgresql

Есть два файла с базы данных MS SQL - mdf и ldf. Задача достать оттуда данные и перенести в PostgreSQL. Это возможно? Если да, то чем и как?

Comment: Тут очень подробно описано [open-file.ru](https://open-file.ru/types/mdf)

Comment: У меня далее написано, что нужно данные из них импортировать в PostgreSQL, а не просто открыть

Comment: 1) Взять MS SQL Server подходящей версии, подключить к нему эти файлы. 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370326/migrate-data-from-ms-sql-to-postgresql

Comment: @БогданСоловьев как-то не похоже "файл .mdf можно открыть Microsoft SQL Server 2016" на "подробно описано" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это внутренние файлы базы данных SQL Server. В таком виде базы обычно никто не переносит.

Их можно подключить к SQL Server - забросить на машину, где установлен SQL Server соответствующей версии (или более новой), подключится к серверу через SQL Server Management Studio, и сделать Attach Database - сервер должен подхватить базу и поднять ее в онлайн.

После этого данные можно перегнать через стандартный Tasks / Export Data (в контекстном меню для базы в той же SQL Server Management Studio, [подключив PostreSQL через ODBC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017). Данные перенести сможете, хранимки и прочее специфическое для MS SQL придется переносить вручную, с переписыванием на диалект PostreSQL.